# Retrieving the values from the paramHankel.scaled() function (mixComp package)

Tags: r

paramHankel.scaled() is a function in mixComp package to be used for determining the components of a finite mixed model. For example, the following piece of codes shows how the function is used:

```
library("mixComp")

set.seed(0)

# construct a Mix object:
    normLocMix <- Mix("norm", discrete = FALSE, w = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3), mean = c(10, 13, 17), sd = 
    c(1, 1, 1))

# generate random samples:
    normLocRMix <- rMix(1000, obj = normLocMix)
# plot the histograms of the random samples:
    plot(normLocRMix, main = "Three component normal mixture", cex.main = 0.9)

# define the function for computing the moments:
    mom.std.norm <- function(j){
       ifelse(j %% 2 == 0, prod(seq(1, j - 1, by = 2)), 0)
    }

    MLE.norm.mean <- function(dat) mean(dat)
    MLE.norm.sd <- function(dat){
       sqrt((length(dat) - 1) / length(dat)) * sd(dat)
    } 
    MLE.norm.list <- list("MLE.norm.mean" = MLE.norm.mean, "MLE.norm.sd" = MLE.norm.sd)

# define the range for parameter values:
    norm.bound.list <- list("mean" = c(-Inf, Inf), "sd" = c(0, Inf))

# create datMix objects:
    normLoc.dM <- RtoDat(normLocRMix, theta.bound.list = norm.bound.list,
                     MLE.function = MLE.norm.list, Hankel.method = "translation",
                     Hankel.function = mom.std.norm)

# define the penalty function:
    pen <- function(j, n){
       j * log(n)
    }

# apply papamHankel.scaled to datMix objects:
    norm_sca_pen <- paramHankel.scaled(normLoc.dM)

# plot the results for both mixtures:
    par(mar=c(5, 5, 1, 1))
    plot(norm_sca_pen)
```

In the last lines we used

```
norm_sca_pen <- paramHankel.scaled(normLoc.dM)
```

The parameters of the mixture model for 2 components are:

```
Parameter estimation for a 2 component 'norm' mixture model:
Function value: 2392.6800

                    w     mean     sd
Component 1:  0.74923 11.88077 2.0151
Component 2:  0.25077 17.14082 0.9251
Converged in 3 iterations.
```

How can I retrieve the values of weights (w), means and sd's from norm_sca_pen for the 2 components model?

Comment: When I ran through your code, the console output of `norm_sca_pen <- paramHankel.scaled(normLoc.dM)` (not when I called the object by itself: `norm_sca_pen`) was `Parameter estimation for a 1 component 'norm' mixture model: Function value: 2486.3396; component 1: w = 1.0, mean = 13.2, sd = 2.9078, Optimization via user entered MLE-function....` it included component 1 by itself, components 1 & 2 only, then all three. However, that's not stored in the object (odd!). You could just run `paramHankel.scaled(normLoc.dM)` to see it all, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I see the results by running the function. What I need is to store automatically the values the function outputs into variables so that I can used them in a program; the number of components, the w's, means, and sd's.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a work-around to get these values. This creates a data frame with each of the three components, along with the `w`, `mean`, and `sd`.

You'll need to add `tidyverse`. (This uses `dplyr` and `purrr`, but `tidyverse` calls both at one time.)

If there were more than three, this would still work.

```
# apply papamHankel.scaled to datMix objects:
norm_sca_pen <- paramHankel.scaled(normLoc.dM)
op <- capture.output(.Last.value)
df1 <- data.frame(Components = as.character(), w = as.numeric(), 
                  mean = as.numeric(), sd = as.numeric())
map(2:length(op),
        function(k) {
          x = strsplit(op[k], ": ")
          y = gsub("  ", " ", x[[1]][2])
          z = strsplit(y, " ")
          df1[nrow(df1) + 1, ] <<- c(x[[1]][1], z[[1]][2], z[[1]][3], z[[1]][4])
        }
)
```